# Angular 6 : Empty path bypass auth guard

Tags: angular, angular-routing, auth-guard

I'm trying to use the Angular router, and I'm having an issue on the empty path . Here's my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [

    { path: 'feed', loadChildren: './feed/feed.module#FeedModule', canLoad: [AuthGuardService] },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginPage },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterPage },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/feed', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
];
```

My AuthGuardService has a method canLoad which always returns false and redirects to the '/login' path :

```
...
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanLoad {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }
  canLoad(route: Route): boolean {

    this.router.navigate([ '/login' ]);
    return false;
  }
}
```

When I go to 'localhost:4200/feed', I'm redirected to '/login'.

But if I go to 'localhost:4200/', the auth guard is ignored and the components of my feed module are displayed.

Do you have any idea why ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does it work if you change `canLoad` to `canActivate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue, sorry for the delay :
I needed to use a component and to use canActivate in order to load the child module

```
{
    path: 'feed',
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
    component: FeedComponent,
    children: [
        {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => FeedModule
}]}
```

Lazy loading for children works as well !

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

I have a working code in my scenario. Check this, if it can help you.

Instead of canLoad, you can use canActivate.

**canActivate** is used to prevent an unauthorized user 
**canLoad** is used to prevent the entire module of app 
in below example you can replace **canActivate** with **canLoad**, if you wish to use canLoad instead.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```

and while writing routes, you can define like below.

```
{ path: 'newLeaveRequest', component: NewLeaveRequestComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{ path: 'pastLeaveRequests', component: PastLeaveRequestComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
```

In app.module.ts
Define AuthGuard in providers.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but I divided my app in different modules (like dashboard, newfeed, ..) and I really want to use my auth guard to prevent angular to load the full module and redirect to the login page ! 
If you look at the angular doc about canLoad, the constructor use the route only : https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad
I've tried examples with canActivate and using components instead of modules, it works perfectly..
I don't understand why here, my empty path redirects on feed but bypass the auth guard